# Que diferença faz usar ou não parênteses ao fazer uma função retornar outra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, parâmetros

Pensei em executar um código teste que aninhasse duas funções para debugar o funcionamento, ficando como abaixo:

```
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a
    
var = b()

print(var(11))
```

Como a princípio havia executado normalmente, resolvi acrescentar mais uma função no aninhamento para testar se usaria a sintaxe correta, então o código ficou assim:

```
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a
def c():
    return b
    
var = c()

print(var(11))
```

Entretanto aqui temos o seguinte erro em `return b`:

> `B() takes 0 positional arguments but was given 1`

Após alguns testes, verifiquei que o erro só era consertado após mudar a linha que retorna a função b para `return b()` explicitando os parênteses, mas a questão é que eu não faço ideia do porque isso funciona e porque o sistema quebra se eu tentar fazer como acima. Ao final da página, a versão do código que funcionou:

```
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a
def c():
    return b()
    
var = c()

print(var(11))
```

Por que estes parênteses fazem diferença?

Answer (score 2):

Antes, um breve resumo. Suponha que eu tenho esta função:

```py
def f():
    return 'ok'
```

Para chamar a função `f` eu preciso dos parênteses, veja a diferença:

```py
# sem parênteses, "f" é a própria função
print(f) # <function f at 0x7f88f5d36dc0>

# com parênteses, "f()" chama (executa) a função, e o retorno dela é passado para print
print(f()) # ok
```

Ou seja, sem parênteses, `f` é a própria função. Ao usar parênteses (`f()`), estou executando a função, e o retorno dela (que no caso é a string `'ok'`) é que é passado para `print`.

Só que a função `f` foi declarada sem parâmetros, ou seja, ao chamá-la eu não posso passar nenhum argumento: não pode ter nada entre os parênteses.
Por isso que `f()` funciona, mas `f(1)` não, pois neste caso estou passando o `1` como argumento, e dá erro:

```py
f() # ok
f(1) # TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Mas se eu declarar a função de forma a receber um parâmetro, aí a situação se inverte:

```py
# agora a função recebe um parâmetro
def f(n):
    return n * 10

# passando "1" como argumento
f(1) # 10
f() # TypeError
```

Agora vamos ao seu caso...

---

Quando você faz `return b`, está retornando a própria função `b` (ela não é executada).
Mas se você faz `return b()` (com os parênteses), está **executando a função `b`**, e está retornando o valor que a função `b` retorna.

Ou seja, sem os parênteses, a função `c` está retornando a função `b`:

```py
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a

def c(): # retorna a função b (atenção: b não é executada)
    return b

var = c()
# var é a função "b"
print(var) # <function b at 0x7fa49838dd30>

print(var(10)) # erro
```

E como `var` agora aponta para a função `b`, então `var(qualquer_coisa)` dá erro, pois a função `b` não tem parâmetros: ela foi declarada com `def b()`, ou seja, não recebe nenhum parâmetro. A única forma de chamá-la corretamente é `b()`, se eu fizer `b(qualquer_coisa)` dará erro. E como `var` contém a função `b`, então a forma correta de chamá-la é `var()`, por isso que `var(10)` dá erro.

---

E por que funciona se adicionar os parênteses?

```py
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a

def c():
    return b() # agora com parênteses, está executando b

var = c()
# veja que agora var é a função "a"
print(var) # <function a at 0x7f9443dedca0>

print(var(10)) # 100
```

Agora funciona porque `b()` (com parênteses) está chamando (executando) a função `b`, e o resultado desta (ou seja, o valor que ela retorna) é também retornado pela função `c`. E como `b` retorna a função `a`, então agora `var` contém a função `a`, e por isso que `var(10)` funciona (pois a função `a` recebe um parâmetro).

---

Se a função `c` fosse escrita assim, ficaria mais fácil entender?

```py
def c():
    # chama a função b e guarda o resultado em uma variável
    resultado = b()
    return resultado
```

Ela chama a função `b` (repare nos parênteses, isso indica que estou chamando a função), e o resultado dela é retornado por `c`. E como `b` retorna a função `a`, então `c` acaba retornando a função `a` também.

Só que em vez de ter essa variável intermediária `resultado`, dá pra fazer tudo de uma vez (`return b()`).

---

Aliás, essa é uma coisa que vejo que muita gente (não só iniciantes) não entende. O `return` não precisa retornar somente uma variável, ele pode retornar qualquer expressão (primeiro a expressão é calculada, e depois o seu resultado é retornado). Tanto que a função `a` poderia ser escrita assim:

```py
def a(num1):
    return num1 * 10
```

Mas aí já estou fugindo demais da pergunta...

Answer (score 0):

Você apenas se perdeu nas referencias das funções armazenadas nas variáveis.

Vamos pegar o exemplo que deu errado:

```
def a(num1):
    resul = num1 * 10
    return resul
    
def b():
    return a

def c():
    return b
```

Nesse exemplo você inicializou uma variável com o retorno de `c`:

```
var = c()
```

`var` contém a função `b`, uma função que recebe 0 parâmetros, então não faz sentido invoca-la como `var(11)`, você deveria invoca-la como `var()`:

```
var_2 = var()
```

Agora temos a variável `var_2` que contém a função `a`. Essa sim é a função que recebe um parâmetro, seria essa a variável que você deveria utilizar no `print`:

```
print(var_2(11))
```

Alternativamente você também poderia fazer `print(c()()(11))`, sem armazenar o retorno das funções em variáveis.

Comment: Testando um pouco mais acabei por entender o que exemplificou, mas ainda não entendo plenamente porque tal função só vem a quebrar na linha de `def b()` sendo que `c()` também não espera nenhum parâmetro e no entanto consegue nos retornar até b antes que o programa quebre. (me refiro ao código original)

Comment: O que parece é que quando eu digito c() ao invés de c ou algo parecido ele considera os contextos de retorno e tudo mais, essa hipótese é correta?